# Python 3 in Visual Studio

Tags: python

Hi there I am a newbie to Python, could someone help me how to convert an input string to ZAR (South African Rand) in order to produce the R symbol before the float amount the user enters? Example: R400.00

Assistance will be highly appreciated.

Comment: as in print("R",the_number)?

Comment: An you at least try to solve the problem before asking us to do it for you?

Comment: Thank you very much I am in a learning curve here, and couldn't make out heads or tails how to implement locale library but I will include my code next time, your advice really helped me great deal.

Answer (score 0):

There is no special format for currency in standard library. You can organize output formatting like that:

```
zar = float(input("ZAR="))
print('R{:.2f}'.format(zar))
```

but in finance calculations better use `Decimal` not `float`.
Or - create own class ZAR() with special method `__str__()` if You really need it )

Comment: Mr. Kolomiets, your advice was extremely helpful, I will include my code next time, I am in a learning curve here and it helps to ask the masters in the Python game, thank you sir, your answer helped a lot!