# How to replace super().__str___?

Tags: python

Day!  I was answering the [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47201846/python-3-in-visual-studio/47202146#47202146) and try to create Class where `__str__` is replaced with my `__str__` like that:

```
from decimal import *

class Zar(Decimal):
    def __init__(self, z):
        self.__z = Decimal(z)

    def __str__(self):
        return 'R{!r}'.format(self.__z)

    def __repr__(self):
        return 'R{!r}'.format(self.__z)

z1 = Zar(3.62)
z2 = Zar(4.12)
z = Zar(z1 + z2)
print('{:.3f}'.format(z))
print(z)
```

I expected output like `R7.740` but it does not work.
Please - say - how to reload **str** method for standard class??
It so boring to do all +-/* ... methods

Now I have output:

```
7.740
RDecimal('7.740000000000000213162820728')
```

Comment: What do you mean with "It does not work"? A `format` with a format specifies of course does not pass through `__str__` and `__repr`__.

Comment: `z` isn't a `Zar`.

Comment: Why are you inheriting from `Decimal` *and* using composition to wrap an instance of `Decimal`?

Comment: @chepner - say how to receive output like R7.740 pls )

Comment: You need to override `__add__` so that `z1 + z2` returns a `Zar` instance; at the moment, `Zar.__add__` is not defined, so `Decimal.__add__` is called to compute `z1 + z2`, and it returns a `Decimal` instance.

Comment: Well, you have the answer in your code already - just define `__str__` as `return 'R{:.3f}'.format(self.__z)` don't use `r` to format - it causes the value to be repr-ed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting `RDecimal(...)` instead of `R...` because of the formatting string you chose, not because you are using the `Decimal.__str__`.

```
In [1]: import decimal

In [2]: a = decimal.Decimal(3.62)

In [4]: str(a)
Out[4]: '3.62000000000000010658141036401502788066864013671875'

In [5]: repr(a)
Out[5]: "Decimal('3.62000000000000010658141036401502788066864013671875')"

In [6]: 'R{!r}'.format(a)
Out[6]: "RDecimal('3.62000000000000010658141036401502788066864013671875')"

In [7]: 'R{}'.format(a)
Out[7]: 'R3.62000000000000010658141036401502788066864013671875'
```

So, if you just change your `__str__` definition to `return 'R{}'.format(self.__z)` you should be fine.